# exec('ping') working in development server but no in production

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, ping

I am writing a ping tool using CakePHP 3. The code works in my development server, returning the correct status `0`. But on the production server it shows always status code `2` instead of `0`, regardless of whether `$ip` is valid or not.

This is my code:

```
public function testDomain(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $ip = $this->request->data['domain'];

        $starttime = microtime(true);

        $stoptime  = microtime(true);
        $total_time = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;

        exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $output, $status);
        print_r($status);
        if (0 == $status) {
            echo $mode = 'up';
            if($total_time <= '500'){
                $result =  'Very Fast';
            }else if($total_time <='1000'){
                $result = 'Fast';
            }else if($total_time <='1500'){
                $result ='Good';
            }else if($total_time <='2500'){
                $result ='Slow';
            }else if($total_time <='3000'){
                $result ='Very Slow';
            }else{
                $result ='down';
            }
            echo $ip.'  '.'is'.'  '.$result; 
        }else{
            echo $mode = 'down';

        }        
    }   
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your development machine is probably Windows and your production server is Linux.

This is what happens when you run your command on Linux:

```
me@mycomputer:~$ ping -n 3 192.168.0.1
connect: Invalid argument
```

`3` is not a valid argument for `ping`.

Your command in Linux shoud be rewritten as:

```
exec("ping -c 3 $ip", $output, $status);
```